# Create Pandas DateTimeIndex with 3 digits millisecond precision

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetimeindex

I have a dataframe like this:

```
lat  lon  year    month  day   hour  minute  second  millisecond
0.0  0.0  2023.0  11.0   22.0  10.0  15.0    34.0    345.0
0.0  0.0  2023.0  11.0   22.0  10.0  23.0    53.0    0.0
...
```

I want to create a `DateTimeIndex` using the date/time columns keeping the millisecond precision, the time is in UTC.

What I did is to extract those columns and created an `DateTimeIndex` using `to_datetime`, the code is:

```
utc_df = df.iloc[:, 2:]
datetimeindex = pd.to_datetime(utc_df, utc=True)
```

the result is:

```
>>> datetimeindex
0        2023-11-22 10:15:34.345000+00:00
1        2023-11-22 10:23:53+00:00
...
Length: 23179, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

The problem is with the millisecond precision.
If the column `millisecond` contains a not-zero value, this is visualised with a microsecond precision, if it's zero it's omitted.

I tried adding `unit="ms"` to `to_datetime`, but the result is the same.

If I remove `utc=True`, the visualisation is what I would like:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(utc_df)
0        2023-11-22 10:15:34.345
1        2023-11-22 10:23:53.000
...
Length: 23179, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

but if I print out just one element:

```
pd.to_datetime(utc_df)[0]
Timestamp('2023-11-22 10:15:34.345000')
```

the microseconds are back.

I tried to modify the format in this way:

```
datetimeindex = datetimeindex.map(
    lambda x: x.isoformat(timespec="milliseconds")
)
```

but this changes also the type of the elements into string and I want `Timestamp`.

Is there a way to have the millisecond with just three digits keeping the `Timestamp` type?

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

As this is an exercise, the only libraries I can use are `pandas` and `numpy`, I cannot import anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have a timezone information, why use `utc=True`?

Just go with:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, 2:])
```

Or

```
pd.to_datetime(df.drop(columns=['lat', 'lon']))
```

If you want to convert from a timezone aware timestamp to a non-timezone aware one:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.drop(columns=['lat', 'lon']), utc=True).dt.tz_localize(None)
```

Output:

```
0   2023-11-22 10:15:34.345
1   2023-11-22 10:23:53.000
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I am using `utc=True` to keep this information as I know the time is in UTC, the original names of the columns were: "UTC Year", "UTC Month" etc. I don't think there is difference between using `utc=True` with removing the timezone and `utc=False`. What I don't understand is the difference between the display precision and the actual precision.

Comment: This is just a different way to represent the data. In the end this shouldn't matter. If you want a specific format you have to convert to a string with `dt.strftime`.

Comment: I would like to have the index as `Timestamp` and not as a string, I am going to leave as it is for now and see what happen. Thanks